# how to get textfield along with keypad in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am doing a project  on gpsnote.  if anyone have any information abt this application plz guide me...

I know this code bt i want textfield should come along with my keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

thanks

Comment: yoou can use becomeFirstResponder for keyboard along with text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set your content over a scroll view and set the scroll view in viewDidLoad:

```
[scrollView setContentSize : CGSizeMake (320, 1040)];
```

then in viewWillAppear add following notification :

For keyboard shown

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

For keyboard hiding

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Following are the two function which are called by the notifications

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

double keyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
double screenHeight =   [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20;

if(textOrigin > screenHeight - keyboardHeight)
{
    double sofset =  textOrigin - (screenHeight - keyboardHeight);
    CGPoint offset = scrollBackGround.contentOffset;
    offset.y += sofset;
    [scrollBackGround setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}

}


- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [scrollBackGround setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

In keyboardWasShown function what we are doing is just getting the height of the keyboard and checking if the textField y axis (i.e textOrigin in the function) are greater than Y axis of keyboard than slide up the content of the scrollview which contain our text field.

NOw How to get the textfield Y axis. For this you have to use the textfield delegate, the following delegate will trigger when your textfield will become first responder

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textOrigin  =   scrollBackGround.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.origin.y + 20(it is status bar height) + yourNavigationBarheight;

// Make sure to make textOrigin an ivar in your .h file
}
```

And finally in keyboardWillBeHidden we are reseting the scrollview contentview